# Множественный выбор с пунктом "другое"

Tags: django

Как сделать поле формы, где пользователь может выбрать несколько значений и/или вписать свое? Т.е. должно получиться что-то вроде этого.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Множественный выбор</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">Яблоки
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">Груши
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">Бананы
  </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Другое">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В html нет инпутов способных это обеспечить. Придётся с помощью css и js превращать пару из select'а и input'а типа text в один виджет.

Comment: Причем тут html? Вопрос, как на Django такое отрисовать.

Comment: Django генерирует пользователю html, а значит не сможет выйти за рамки его возможностей.

Comment: Разумеется. Но в html это возможно, и я даже написал, какой код надо сгенерировать. Я не знаю, как сделать такое поле, какой виджет использовать.

Comment: Тогда решительно не понимаю вашей проблемы. Вы не знаете как в форме объявить два поля? Не знаете как делать валидацию формы по двум полям? Или вы хотите, сделать нестандартное поле djang-формы, отображающееся в два поля html-формы, но не знаете как?

Comment: "Не знаете как делать валидацию формы по двум полям?" -
Скорее всего, вот это то что мне нужно.